# How to show that in ABCD, if (AB) isn’t parallel to (CD), then the line joining the middle points of AD and BC is concurrent to (AB) and (CD)?

Tags: geometry

I have to show that in a non complex quadrilateral ABCD if (II’) is
the line joining the middle points I and I’ of AD and CD then the lines (AB), (CD) and (II’) are either parallel or concurrent.

For the parallel case it is pretty easy using the bimedian of a trapezoid, but for the concurrent case I can’t seem to find much and even my professor isn’t able to solve the exercise, he said that he forgot to add the condition that (AD)//(BC) but in this case it is almost trivial and with all examples I have drawn it does work even without this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Counter Example

[image: http://imgur.com/gallery/8pcdfFt]

The image clearly shows that the 3 lines are not concurrent

Comment: Yes, I found the answer, the concurrent part only works if (AB)//(A’B’)